# What is the setImmediate() equivalent that is supported by browsers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I created a library for Node and the browser and want to call an external endpoint which responds with a stream. Since this stream might never end the client should be able to abort the process.

```
public async observe(): Promise<() => void> {
    const abortController = new AbortController();

    const response = await fetch('url', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        body: { /* ... */ },
        signal: abortController.signal,
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        // handle error
    }

    setImmediate(async () => {
        // parse response.body ( stream )
    });

    return () => {
        abortController.abort();
    };
}
```

I used `setImmediate` because I must return the abort function first, otherwise this function would never reach the return statement because it keeps parsing the stream.

Unfortunately `setImmediate` is not supported by browsers ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate?retiredLocale=de#browser_compatibility )

Does someone know what to use instead?

Comment: try-finally? Equally cursed.

Comment: Why not just use setTimeout with a timeout of zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

If you want a microTask you could use a Promise.

```
Promise.resolve().then(
  () => console.log('there')); 
console.log('hello');
```

For a normal Task, you could use `setTimeout`;

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('there'));
console.log('hello');
```

There is also the `requestAnimationFrame`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

It's been pointed out why not just use `try finally`.  But one issue with that, if your processing the stream in finally, then by the time the caller gets the `abort` function it's too late.  But rather than using something like `setImmediate`, it would actually be cleaner if you just return a promise for the streaming, and the abort function together.

eg.

```
public async observe(): Promise<() => void> {
    const abortController = new AbortController();
    const response = await fetch('url', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        body: { /* ... */ },
        signal: abortController.signal,
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
        // handle error
    }
    return {
       abort: () => abortController.abort(),
       promise: async () => {
          // parse response.body ( stream )
       }
    };
}
```

You can then call like ->

```
const {abort, promise} = observe();
setTimeout(() => abort(), 5000); //abort in 5 seconds
await promise;
```

Comment: Would `try { return ... } finally { ... }` work, too? They just seem to need to return before executing the parsing code. Of course, you could also have `catch` in case an error occurs in the `try`.

Comment: @caTS  I believe the OP is returning a function, and he want's that returning to the caller to be able to abort, but he is also wanting to process the stream at the same time.  As such `finally` is going to get called before the caller has the abort function returned.  IOW: He is going to get the abort function after the stream is complete.  Personally I would use a Asynchronous Iterator for that purpose, as currently this takes program flow out of sync.

Comment: @caTS Actually thinking about this more, it's maybe even easier if the OP returns a Promise and the Abort Controller's abort..  `return { abort: () => abortController.abort(), promise: theStreamingProc() }`